# Using sensor data in Android

Tags: android, android-sensors

So I'm working on an app where I would like to get the ambient temperature and humidity. Going off the developer site I have come up with this:

```
public class TempSensorActivity extends Activity implements SensorEventListener {
    private SensorManager mSensorManager;
    private Sensor mTemp;

    @Override
    public final void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_temp_sensor);

        // Get an instance of the sensor service, and use that to get an instance of
        // a particular sensor.
        mSensorManager = (SensorManager) getSystemService(Context.SENSOR_SERVICE);
        mTemp = mSensorManager.getDefaultSensor(Sensor.TYPE_AMBIENT_TEMPERATURE);
    }

    @Override
    public final void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {
        // Do something here if sensor accuracy changes.
    }

    @Override
    public void onSensorChanged(SensorEvent event) {
        float degreesCelsius = event.values[0];
        // Do something with this sensor data.
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        // Register a listener for the sensor.
        super.onResume();
        mSensorManager.registerListener(this, mTemp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        // Be sure to unregister the sensor when the activity pauses.
        super.onPause();
        mSensorManager.unregisterListener(this);
    }
}
```

Now I have looked over the documentation and I am wondering 1. What exactly would I want to do (if anything) with `onAccuracyChanged` and `onSensorChanged`? I want to get the temperature after pressing a button and I only need that instance of it, I don't need to notice an on going change. 2. How exactly would I pass the temperature value into my `Main Activity`? Would I have to use a bundle for that?

Comment: this might help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506421/obtaining-sensor-data-for-x-seconds-after-onclick-of-a-button

Comment: That doesn't help me too much, I want to pass the value from this Activity into my Main Activity, unless it would be better practice to include this in my Main

Answer (score 0):

as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8506421/obtaining-sensor-data-for-x-seconds-after-onclick-of-a-button) you have to register the listener in your activity and unregister it in button onClick. Then access the values from activity in onClick to do what ever you want on Button click. Here I am sending those values to AnOtherActivity.Class.

```
btnClick.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListnener() ) {

   void OnClick(View v){

      //unregister the receiver...

       new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            sensorManager.unregisterListener(listener);

            // access values and send to AnOtherActivity
           Intent i = new Intent(MyActivity.this, AnOtherActivity.class);
           i.putExtra("DegreeCelsius", degreesCelsius);
           startActivity(i);

        }
    }, theTimeInMilliseconds); 

   }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

1) If you needed to use `onAccuracyChanged` you would know so. It is used to detect if the accuracy of the sensor has changed, so it really depends on what your uses are from the sensor. In most cases there will probably be no use.

2) `onSensorChanged` - Here is where you get the readings that are updated from the sensor, or in other words - this is where you will do most of your work regarding the values retrieved from the sensor you are using.

3) I see no reason using the `Sensor` methods in your `MainActivity` - I have done so myself and it has run flawlessly.

4) If you need to get a temp reading only when you click the button, in your `onClick` method I would register the listener, get the reading, then unregister the listener so no resources are "wasted". something like this:

```
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View arg0) {

                  mSensorManager.registerListener(Mainactivity.this, mTemp, SensorManager.SENSOR_DELAY_NORMAL);
//declare degreeCelsius as global variable in your Activity
degreesCelsius = event.values[0];
//Do whatever you want with the value
mSensorManager.unregisterListener(Mainactivity.this);

                }

            });
```

Hope this helps!